# Why JSON Encode is returning empty array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a PHP array which i want to access it in Javascript.

My PHP array:

```
array(4) { 
[1]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(3) 
["symptoms"]=> array(6) { [0]=> int(18) [1]=> int(19) 
[2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(21) [4]=> int(22) [5]=> int(23) } } [2]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(5) 
["symptoms"]=> array(0) { } } 
[3]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(5) ["symptoms"]=> array(0) { } }   [4]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(5) ["symptoms"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(18) [1]=> int(19) [2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(21) } } }
```

I encoded the above array in javascript but it's returning empty in console.

[image]

```
{% block page_js %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        EvaluationQuiz();
    });
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "inline";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }

    var checkBoxPageHeader = "Check off the ones that apply to you";
    var defaultPageHeader = "Body Evaluation";
    var ratingOptions = <?php echo json_encode($ratingJson); ?>;
    console.log(ratingOptions);
    $('.rating-radio a').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('CheckOn');
      $(this).addClass('CheckOn');
      $(this).parent(".rating-radio").find('a span').removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('span').addClass('active');
      $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        // Data Question ID is id of Ratin Question
        console.log($(this).attr('data-question-id'));

        console.log(ratingOptions[$(this).attr('data-question-id')].le_value);
      if (ratingOptions[$(this).attr('data-question-id')] != undefined) {
        // Radio Value is the clicked radio value
        var radio_value = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').val();
        var min_value = ratingOptions[$(this).attr('data-question-id')].le_value;
        selSymptoms = ratingOptions[$(this).attr('data-question-id')].symptoms;
        if (selSymptoms.length > 0) {
          $.each(selSymptoms, function(key, symptomId) {
            if (radio_value <= min_value) {
              $('.check-list li label input[id="symptom_' + symptomId + '"]').parent().click();
            } else {
              $('.check-list li label input[id="symptom_' + symptomId + '"]').parent().click();
            }
          });
        }
      }

    });

    $('.nextcat').click(function() {
        saveEvaluationQuizClientDetails();
    });

    // Validate User/Client Data When Next Button is clicked (Up or DOWN)
    $('#client_detail_down, #client_detail_up').click(function(e) {
      saveEvaluationQuizClientDetails();
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-front-validate-evaluation-quiz-client-details'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#signup-form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                console.log(data.status);
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            $('.error-box').html(data.responseText);
        }
      });
    });


    function saveEvaluationQuizClientDetails() {
      //$("div#eval_ajax_loader").addClass('show');
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-front-save-evaluation-quiz-client-details'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#signup-form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('saved');
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log('Not saved');
        }
      });
    }
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php foreach ($ratingQuestions as $rkey => $ratingQuestion): ?>
<?php
    if ($ratingQuestion['apply_symptom_min'] > 0) {
        $ratingJson[$ratingQuestion['id']]['le_value'] = $ratingQuestion['apply_symptom_min'];
        $ratingJson[$ratingQuestion['id']]['symptoms'] = $ratingQuestion['symptoms'];
var_dump($ratingJson);

    }
?>
<? endforeach;?>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much for the help in advance. Let me know if any further detail is required. The json_encode function is returning an empty array.

Thanks again.

Comment: you could look at the _direct output_ of your json_encode. and try to `var_dump()` the variable itself for comparison.

Comment: Is the PHP code before or after your js? Are they in the same file? Please give us more info.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson both are in same file js is below php.

Comment: And where is the `var_dump` located that you show above?

Comment: Please show us the complete code from when you create the array, var_dump it and try to json encode it. There must be something else going on that we can't see.

Comment: @Thomas check updated question.

Comment: What about JSON.stringify() js method to parse json to string instead of php json encode.

Comment: Again, please show us the _complete_ code from the loop to the json_encode() (in one big code block).

Comment: @JesseJay - How would `JSON.stringify()` help or even be used in that code? The OP has an array in PHP and wants to output it as a json object in JS.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson check updated question.

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I asked for the complete code from the PHP code to the json_encode. We need to see what happens in between them. Also, are you using some templating engine? That could be highly relevant.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson https://pastebin.com/EusbkrUj here you go!

Comment: Template Engine is volt @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Don't post off-site links to your code. All relevant code needs to be in the question itself. Off-site links can change/be deleted and then the question is irrelevant for future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Start index from 0 or use string instead.

Comment: It seems that you have initialized php array below javascript code?

Comment: @ZainFarooq it's above JS code!

Comment: Ok initialize this array `$array =array('name'=>'xyz','id'=>'123');` and then encode it

Comment: see what happens

Comment: @ZainFarooq the above is working. So it seems something is wrong with my array structure which is `array(4) { [1]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(3) ["symptoms"]=> array(6) { [0]=> int(18) [1]=> int(19) [2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(21) [4]=> int(22) [5]=> int(23) } } [2]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(5) ["symptoms"]=> array(0) { } } [3]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(5) ["symptoms"]=> array(0) { } } [4]=> array(2) { ["le_value"]=> int(5) ["symptoms"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(18) [1]=> int(19) [2]=> int(20) [3]=> int(21) } } }`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please check the updated array i think i was missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you did there:

You expect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ...
   var ratingOptions = <?php echo json_encode($ratingJson); ?>;
   ...
</script>
```

to turn into an valid jsArray for `ratingOptions`, when the javascript is executed?

well, while this usually should work with vanilla html/php/js - I assume the templating engine you are using is "shredding" the template into several parts - and including your javascript-code, where `$ratingJson` is not a valid context.

Comment: What's the solution? @dognose

Comment: @Imaduddin you have to figure that out on your own. Read the documentation on how the template file is processed, then you will find a way to achieve what's desired.